# How to use the Windows MessageBox() C function?

Tags: c, windows, messagebox

Can someone tell me how I can display a message box in C that can print variables?

I mean like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

main()
{
    int x = 5;
    MessageBox(0, "Variable x is equal to %d", "Variable", 0); 
    /* Where do I specify the variable so that 5 will display?*/

    getch();
}
```

To look like this:

```
          Variable

 Variable x is equal to 5.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `main` function lacks a return type!

Comment: @urzeit My compiler doesn't usually need it. Besides, I just made this to test possible solutions. I would always remember that when coding for real.

Comment: @Wix as an advice, do it also in your test programs. It creates muscle memory and makes you less prone to forget it in "real" apps.

Answer (score 6):

[`MessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) itself doen't support `printf` like formatting. You'll have to use [`snprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) for that:

```
char buf[1024];
snprintf(buf, 1024, "Variable x is equal to %d", x);

MessageBox(0, buf, "Variable", 0);
```

Comment: Remember that snprintf is only available in C++11 and above.

Comment: @urzeit: we are talking C here. It's been in the standard library as long as I can remember.

Comment: Didn't notice the C tag.

Answer (score 0):

I want to debug multiple variables of type integer or string as a list within a single MessageBox so that I do not have to press the button repeatedly. This extension to #Bart's answer does it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char debugMsg [1024] = ""; // buffer for debug message

void debugStr (char* varName, char* var) {
  snprintf (debugMsg, sizeof (debugMsg), "%s%s=%s\n", debugMsg, 
    varName, var);}

void debugInt (char* varName, int   var) {
  snprintf (debugMsg, sizeof (debugMsg), "%s%s=%d\n", debugMsg, 
    varName, var);}
  
void main () {    
  char myStrA [] = "letter A", myStrZ [] = "letter Z";
  int  myIntA    = 65,         myIntZ    = 90;
  // Concat debug message from multiple vars of type integer or string:
  debugStr   ("myStrA", myStrA);
  debugInt   ("myIntA", myIntA);
  debugStr   ("myStrZ", myStrZ);
  debugInt   ("myIntZ", myIntZ);
  MessageBox (NULL, debugMsg, "Debug", MB_OK); // returns this list:
  //           myStrA=letter A
  //           myIntA=65
  //           myStrZ=letter Z
  //           myIntZ=90
  memset     (debugMsg, 0, sizeof debugMsg); // clear debug message
}
```